# Why is the determinant of the induced metric not always 0?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, determinant

I have a function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\times S^{n-2}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}, \varphi(t,\vec{\theta})$. Wanting to compute the determinant of the induced metric of the function, I wrote that

\begin{equation}g=(D\varphi)^{\intercal}(D\varphi)=\begin{bmatrix}\varphi_{t}^{\intercal}\\\varphi_{\vec{\theta}}^{\intercal}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\varphi_{t}&\varphi_{\vec{\theta}}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\varphi_{t}^{\intercal}\varphi_{t} & \varphi_{t}^{\intercal}\varphi_{\vec{\theta}}\\\varphi_{\vec{\theta}}^{\intercal}\varphi_{t}&\varphi_{\vec{\theta}}^{\intercal}\varphi_{\vec{\theta}}\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
and \begin{equation}|g|=|\varphi_{t}^{\intercal}\varphi_{t}-(\varphi_{t}^{\intercal}\varphi_{\vec{\theta}})(\varphi_{\vec{\theta}}^{\intercal}\varphi_{\vec{\theta}})^{-1}(\varphi_{\vec{\theta}}^{\intercal}\varphi_{t})|\cdot|(\varphi_{\vec{\theta}}^{\intercal}\varphi_{\vec{\theta}})|=0\end{equation}

I took $\varphi_{\vec{\theta}}$ and $\varphi_{t}$ to be sub-matrices of $g$ and used the formula for the determinant of a block matrix:
\begin{equation}\det\begin{pmatrix}A& B\\ C& D\end{pmatrix} =  \det\left(A - B D^{-1} C\right)\det(D)\end{equation}

I need help finding the mistake above, since $|g|$ is obviously not always $0$.

Comment: Yes I agree, but in my second line I took the first determinant to be 0, since the second matrix, after multiplying the matrices, is equal to the first one, giving 0

Comment: Ah, so you did. Never mind.

Comment: Isn’t $\varphi_\theta$ an $n\times (n-2)$ matrix?

Comment: Yes, it is a n by n-2 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the formula $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ when $A$ and $B$ are non-square (hence non-invertible) matrices.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a mistake we all make at some point. :) Please accept the answer (or the other answer) when you are satisfied, so that the question will not stay on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, the induced metric $h$ is a 2-form on a base manifold $N$ mapping to some point $p$ at manifold $M$ such that we build this relation $N \stackrel{f}{\to} M$ given by isometry $h(u, v) = g(f_*u, f_* v)$. In this sense, due given equality, we obtain induced metric $h_{ij}$ as expression $g_{\alpha\beta} f^\alpha_{;i} f^\beta_{;j}$. The matrix must be positive definite for any point which does not degenerate the pushforward rank $\mbox{rank}(f_*) = \mbox{dim}(N)$.

Comment: Yes, I know. However I need a way of computing the above determinant, and I don't understand why my method would return that it is always $0$.

Comment: imh, the correct formula is $D\varphi \, D\varphi^\intercal$ instead. Otherwise, your tensor becomes a scalar.

Comment: But if $D\varphi D\varphi^{\intercal}$=$(D\varphi^{\intercal} D\varphi)^\intercal$, then the determinant of this matrix will be equal to the other one, and the same problem arises, giving 0, right?

Comment: No. The matrix product $u u^\intercal$ results into a matrix. The product $u^\intercal u$ is a scalar. And the transpose operation $(u u^\intercal)^\intercal$ is equal to $u u^\intercal$ as well.